# Create database on an android project

Tags: android, sqlite, android-studio

I'm working on a project on android studio, and we need to create a database. I understand how databases work, but I can't understand how to create it. In my project, I got the class DataBaseHandler where I create the tables of a database.

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

//DataBase name
public static final String TABLE_PERSON = "person";
public static final String TABLE_SCORE = "score";
public static final String TABLE_ALBUM = "album";
public static final String TABLE_FRIENDSHIP = "friendship";
public static final String TABLE_RENDEZVOUS = "rendezvous";
public static final String TABLE_AVAILABILITY = "availability";

//Key name
//Key Person Name
public static final String PERSON_FIRST_NAME = "firstName";
public static final String PERSON_NAME = "name";
public static final String PERSON_LOGIN = "login";
public static final String PERSON_PLACE = "place";
public static final String PERSON_BIRTHDAY = "birthday";
public static final String PERSON_LANGUAGE = "language";
public static final String PERSON_HAIR = "hair";
public static final String PERSON_EYES = "eyes";
public static final String PERSON_PASSWORD = "password";
public static final String PERSON_DESCRIPTION = "description";
public static final String PERSON_GENDER = "gender";
public static final String PERSON_ORIENTATION = "orientation";
//Key Score Name
public static final String SCORE_LOGINGET = "loginGet";
public static final String SCORE_LOGINGIVE = "loginGive";
public static final String SCORE_QUOTATION = "quotation";
//Key Album Name
public static final String ALBUM_LOGIN = "login";
public static final String ALBUM_PICTURE = "picture";
//Key Friendship Name
public static final String FRIENDSHIP_LOGIN1 = "login1";
public static final String FRIENDSHIP_LOGIN2 = "login2";
public static final String FRIENDSHIP_CHAT = "chat";
//Key RendezVous Name
public static final String RENDEZVOUS_LOGIN1 = "login1";
public static final String RENDEZVOUS_LOGIN2 = "login2";
public static final String RENDEZVOUS_MEETING = "meeting";
//Key Availability Name
public static final String AVAILABILITY_LOGIN = "login";
public static final String AVAILABILITY_DATE = "date";

//Drop Table
public static final String PERSON_TABLE_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_PERSON + ";";
public static final String SCORE_TABLE_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SCORE + ";";
public static final String ALBUM_TABLE_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_ALBUM + ";";
public static final String FRIENDSHIP_TABLE_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_FRIENDSHIP + ";";
public static final String RENDEZVOUS_TABLE_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_RENDEZVOUS + ";";
public static final String AVAILABILITY_TABLE_DROP = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_AVAILABILITY + ";";

//Create Table
//Person
public static final String PERSON_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_PERSON + " (" +
                PERSON_LOGIN + " TEXT PRIMARY KEY, " +
                PERSON_PLACE + " TEXT not nul, " +
                PERSON_FIRST_NAME + " TEXT not null, " +
                PERSON_NAME + " TEXT not null, " +
                PERSON_BIRTHDAY + " TEXT not null, " +
                PERSON_LANGUAGE + " TEXT not null, " +
                PERSON_HAIR + " TEXT not null, " +
                PERSON_EYES + " TEXT not null, " +
                PERSON_PASSWORD + " TEXT not null, " +
                PERSON_DESCRIPTION + " TEXT not null, " +
                PERSON_GENDER + " TEXT not null, " +
                PERSON_ORIENTATION + " TEXT not null);";
//Score
public static final String SCORE_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_SCORE + " (" +
                SCORE_LOGINGIVE + " TEXT not null references " + TABLE_PERSON + ", " +
                SCORE_LOGINGET + " TEXT not null references " + TABLE_PERSON + ", " +
                SCORE_QUOTATION + " INTEGER not null, PRIMARY KEY (" +
                SCORE_LOGINGIVE + ", " + SCORE_LOGINGET + "));";
//Album
public static final String ALBUM_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_ALBUM + " (" +
                ALBUM_LOGIN + " TEXT not null references " + TABLE_PERSON + ", " +
                ALBUM_PICTURE + " TEXT not null, PRIMARY KEY(" +
                ALBUM_LOGIN + ", " + ALBUM_PICTURE + "));";
//Friendship
public static final String FRIENDSHIP_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_FRIENDSHIP + " (" +
                FRIENDSHIP_LOGIN1 + " TEXT not null references " + TABLE_PERSON + ", " +
                FRIENDSHIP_LOGIN2 + " TEXT not null references " + TABLE_PERSON + ", " +
                FRIENDSHIP_CHAT + " TEXT, PRIMARY KEY (" +
                FRIENDSHIP_LOGIN1 + ", " + FRIENDSHIP_LOGIN2 + "));";
//Rendezvous
public static final String RENDEZVOUS_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_RENDEZVOUS + " (" +
                RENDEZVOUS_LOGIN1 + " TEXT not null references" + TABLE_PERSON + ", " +
                RENDEZVOUS_LOGIN2 + " TEXT not null references" + TABLE_PERSON + ", " +
                RENDEZVOUS_MEETING + " TEXT not null, PRIMARY KEY" +
                RENDEZVOUS_LOGIN1 + ", " + RENDEZVOUS_LOGIN2 + "), FOREIGN KEY(" +
                RENDEZVOUS_LOGIN1 + ", " + RENDEZVOUS_MEETING + ") references " + TABLE_AVAILABILITY + ", FOREIGN KEY(" +
                RENDEZVOUS_LOGIN2 + ", " + RENDEZVOUS_MEETING + ") references " + TABLE_AVAILABILITY + ");";
//Availability
public static final String AVAILABILITY_TABLE_CREATE =
        "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_AVAILABILITY + " (" +
                AVAILABILITY_LOGIN + " TEXT not null references" + TABLE_PERSON + ", " +
                AVAILABILITY_DATE + " TEXT not null, PRIMARY KEY (" +
                AVAILABILITY_LOGIN + ", " + AVAILABILITY_DATE + "));";

public DatabaseHandler(Context context, String name, SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory factory, int version) {
    super(context, name, factory, version);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
    db.execSQL(PERSON_TABLE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(SCORE_TABLE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(ALBUM_TABLE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(FRIENDSHIP_TABLE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(RENDEZVOUS_TABLE_CREATE);
    db.execSQL(AVAILABILITY_TABLE_CREATE);
}

@Override
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    db.execSQL(PERSON_TABLE_DROP);
    db.execSQL(SCORE_TABLE_DROP);
    db.execSQL(ALBUM_TABLE_DROP);
    db.execSQL(FRIENDSHIP_TABLE_DROP);
    db.execSQL(RENDEZVOUS_TABLE_DROP);
    db.execSQL(AVAILABILITY_TABLE_DROP);
    onCreate(db);
}
```

So, here the question,how do I create the database (and where? In an other Class) and how do I fill these tables. I know my questions seem vague, but I've searched all day, and I'm giving up. Or you have a link to a good tutorial.

I've started with this method who has to fill my database with the users method. But as I said earlier, no database are created.

```
public static void createPerson(User user,SQLiteDatabase db){
    db.execSQL("insert into"+TABLE_PERSON+"values ("+user.getLoginStr()+", "+user.getPlaceStr()+", "+user.getPlaceStr()+", "+user.getFirstNameStr()+", "+user.getNameStr()+", "+user.getBirthdayStr()+", "+user.getLanguageStr()+", "+user.getHairStr()+", "+user.getEyesStr()+", "+user.getPassword()+", "+user.getDescriptionStr()+", "+user.getGenderStr()+", "+user.getOrientationStr());
}
```

Thank you a lot if you can help me, or you've read me

Answer (score 0):

try these link http://www.javatpoint.com/android-sqlite-tutorial
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm

for insert use this code

```
DatabaseHandler databaseHandler = new DatabaseHandler(context); 
SQLiteDatabase sql = databaseHandler.getWritableDatabase();
ContentValues values = new ContentValues();  
values.put(KEY_NAME, value); 
values.put(KEY_NAME, value); 
sql.insert(TABLE_Name, null, values);  
sql.close();
```